# Binary Search versus LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of floating point data in which I want to find the index just below a passed value.  A simplified example:

```
double[] x= {1.0, 1.4, 2.3, 5.6, 7.8};
double[] y= {3.4, 8.2, 5.3, 8.1, 0.5};
int lowerIndex = BinaryIndexSearch(x, 2.0);  // should return 1
```

The intent is that an interpolation will then be performed with `x` and `y` using `lowerIndex` and `lowerIndex+1`.

The binary index search algorithm looks like

```
    int BinaryIndexSearch(double[] x, double value)
    {
        int upper = x.Length - 1;
        int lower = 0;
        int pivot;

        do
        {
            pivot = (upper + lower) / 2;

            if (value >= x[pivot])
            {
                lower = pivot + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                upper = pivot - 1;
            }
        }
        while (value < x[pivot] || value >= x[pivot + 1]);

        return pivot;
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this with LINQ?  Would it typically be faster?  The comparison operation at the end of the do..while loop is the "hottest" line of code my program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LINQ will not be more efficient than a binary search.

However, you are re-inventing the existing [`Array.BinarySearch` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx).

If the element is not found, `Array.BinarySearch` will return the bitwise complement (`~` operator) of the location where it ought to be.

Answer (score 6):

Linq is written over IEnumerable. It is not meant for performance. As a general rule of thumb all algorithms that have intimate knowledge of the data structure used will be faster than a generic solution (like LINQ is).