# writing efficient query to search a dataset index record with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

i am replacing old binary search functions with linq queries in my project.
i cant figure out why linq queries is so slow compare to the binary search method (must have been doing something wrong).

**the execute of this part of the program takes 2-3 seconds with binary search compare to almost 60 sec with the linq searches i have written.**

basically what i am trying to do is return index of dataset record.

i am looping  trough datatable with 5000 records and passing the primary key of the datatable to the linq query \ binary search function in order to search that primary key in a global dataset and return the index of the record.

i must have been doing something wrong i will be greatful for your advice how to write this query more efficent.

**the 2 functions of the linq query:**

```
 Public Function existInDs(ByVal spcall As String) As Boolean
            'check if exist
            Dim spIsExist As Boolean = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("SpCall") = spcall)
            Return spIsExist
        End Function

        Private Function getIndexDsWithLinq(ByVal sp As Integer) As Integer

            Dim SpCall = CType(sp, String)

            If existInDs(SpCall) = False Then
                Return -1
            Else
                Dim index As Integer = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("SpCall") = SpCall) _
                           .Select(Function(x) db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.IndexOf(x)).Distinct.SingleOrDefault()
                Return index
            End If

        End Function
```

**i have also tried that:**

```
  Private Function getIndexDsWithLinq(ByVal sp As Integer) As Integer
    Dim SpCall = CType(sp, String)
    Dim columnIndex As Integer
    Dim dr() As DataRow
    dr = Me.db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Select("SpCall='" & SpCall & "'")
    If dr.Length > 0 Then
        columnIndex = Me.db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("SpCall") = sp AndAlso x.Field(Of Date?)("Changed").HasValue).Select(Function(x) Me.db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.IndexOf(x)).Distinct.SingleOrDefault()
        Return columnIndex
    Else
        Return -1
    End If
End Function
```

**that is the(classic) binary search function:**

```
  Private Function Searchbinary(ByVal SpCall As Integer) As Integer

    Dim lower As Long = 0
    Dim upper As Long = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Dim middle As Long
    Dim rowNum As Integer

    Do
        middle = (lower + upper) / 2
        If SpCall < CType(db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(middle).Item("SpCall"), Integer) Then
            upper = middle - 1
        Else
            lower = middle + 1
        End If

    Loop While CType(db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(middle).Item("SpCall"), Integer) <> SpCall And lower <= upper

    If CType(db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(middle).Item("SpCall"), Integer) = SpCall Then
        rowNum = middle

    Else
        rowNum = -1
    End If

    Return rowNum

End Function
```

Comment: If you know that the values are sorted, binary search _will_ be faster than Linq that does not know about the sort and has to filter all values. Not sure whether it accounts for all the difference though.

Comment: Interestingly, why is linear search much slower than binary search.

Comment: @IvanStoev If you have 1M rows, Linq has to (at worst) go though _all_ 1M rows to find a match, while a binary search of a sorted collection will only need to look at 20 rows at worst.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That wasn't a question :)

Comment: hi @Joachim, the values are sorted, so if you are right i will stick to the binary search.

Comment: ok so just now i found that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463128/binary-search-versus-linq-select-statement                                                                                              i will use Array.BinarySearch() or stick to the original binary search function.

Comment: @IvanStoev Whoops, sorry, I read it as a question :) Point still stands for jonathana though, a binary search will cause fewer comparisons and Linq will have an extremely hard time keeping up.

Comment: Upvoted for using the word "efficient" to refer to actual runtime efficiency, instead of whatever strange attributes it usually refers to around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to summery all the discussion, first as 
@Joachim said - "if you know that the values are sorted, binary search will be faster than Linq", i searched that topic over the web and also here in stackoverflow and also measured processing time of binary search vs few variations of LINQ queries/Lambda expressions (you can see comparing in comments) , my final conclusion is that @Joachim is right. lambda expressions are the best solution **when there are multiple conditions** and binary search is the best solution when there are no conditions and values are sorted (for minimum process time).

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you want to get first occurence of matching data and return its `rowIndex`.

The simplest way to achieve that using Linq is:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = Me.db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("SpCall") = SpCall).FirstOrDefault()
Dim rowIndex As Integer = Me.db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows().IndexOf(dr)
```

Please, check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I tested code on below example:

```
Sub Main

    Dim dt As DataTable = CreateDt()
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.AsEnumerable() _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("SpCall") = 5).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)
    Console.WriteLine(rowIndex)

End Sub

'below function is created only dor testing purposes
Public Function CreateDt() As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns().Add(New DataColumn("SpCall", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50000
        Dim randomValue As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((50 - 1 + 1) * Microsoft.VisualBasic.Rnd())) + 1
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object(){randomValue})
    Next

    Return dt
End Function
```

It's executed in less then 1 sec.

Comment: thank you @Maciej i will try your code tomorrow and report. interestingly when i think about it inner join with linq probably is the best solution for minimum run time (i think) if that is right probably the mechanism is different from the lambda expressions or the binary search, but how linq works behind the scenes is above my understanding. also i think that the lambda expressions are the best solution when there are multiple conditions and binary search is the best solution when there are no conditions and values are sorted. anyway that is only assumptions right now.

Comment: hi @Maciej i tryed your code, it is more efficient than the linq query i wrote but still the binary search takes 1 second and the linq query takes 16 seconds...i will stick to binary search. tnx!

Comment: For large amount of data binary search is usually faster than Linq. Cheers, Maciej.